# Django 1.7.7 get object count in template through double relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have 3 models, Entry model and Category model, and I have created intermediate model CategoryEntry.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_text = models.TextField()

class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    entries = models.ManyToManyField(Entry, through='CategoryEntry')

class CategoryEntry(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="related_entry_categories")
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can I get in template Users total Entry count.
For example I can get total users Category count with

```
{{ user.category_set.count }}
```

So I tried many different ways, but don't get how to follow next relation

```
{{ user.category_set.entries.count}}
{{ user.category_set.categoryentry_set.count}}
{{ user.category_set.all.categoryentry_set.count}}
{{ user.category_set.related_entry_categories.count }}
```

Is this even possible (good thing to do) to count in template? Or is there better way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your queries don't make sense because `category_set` is a *collection* of objects rather than a single object, so you cannot simply ask for `category_set.entries.count`

first you have to think about what you want... do you want:

- individual count of entries *for each* category in `category_set`?
- or total count of entries across *all* categories in `category_set`?

For the former you need to [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the queryset. this will have to be done in the view rather than template  because the method needs arguments:

```
from django.db.models import Count

user_categories = user.category_set.annotate(entry_count=Count('entries'))
# then pass the user_categories queryset into your template along with user
```

you can then iterate over `user_categories` in the template to display individual counts:

```
{% for category in user_categories %}
    No. of entries: {{ category.entry_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

For the latter you can use [`aggregate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate), again in the view:

```
from django.db.models import Count

total = user.category_set.aggregate(entry_count=Count('entries'))
# note that aggregate method returns a dict:
print total['entry_count'] 
# then pass total['entry_count'] as a value into your template along with user
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this really cleared things out to me - was really confused about the collection of objects vs object, now I got it. And yes, I needed the second aggregate version, thanks for that :)